# iOs / Blackberry CSS z-index

Tags: css, ios, blackberry, z-index

I have a weird problem with iOs / Blackberry - Devices. So I have a page with a slideshow and a dropdown navigation. Everything works fine in Safari, Firefox, etc, except for those iOs and Blackberry devices. There it seems like the slideshow overlie the navigation dropdown and so making it useless. I already checked the z-index of both and the z-index of the navigation dropdown is higher than the z-index of the slideshow. I tried several things and finally deleted the "position: relative" of the slideshow. Then it seemed to work, but it doesn't, because now the elements of the slideshow still overlie the navigation. It is visible now, but you cannot use it.

Here is the link to the page: [Here](http://www.varusmarketing.de)

Sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot debug since I don't have a blackberry, but have you tried adding a z-index to the sibling of #slideshow that is also a parent of the navagation?

```
#globalHeader {
  z-index: 999;
}
```